# error:`runtime compiler is not loaded` in aot mode

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-aot, angular-compiler

In my angular 6 project I want to define all routes of `DashboardModule` as a children of `profile` route in `AppModule` like below code

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    loadChildren: () => DashboardModule
  }
```

this code run with JIT compiler (while `aot:false` in `angular.json` file)
but giving **runtime compiler is not loaded** error with AOT compiler( while `aot:true`).

so my question is, is there any way to load `DashboardModule's` routes as a children of profile route in `AppModule` without lazy loading `DashboardModule`?